# PythonMagick lens correction

Tags: python, imagemagick

I need help using ImageMagick in Python, I have a C# code that applies lens correction using `MagickNet`, the sequence is as it follows:

```cs
using ImageMagick;

// Step 0: Loading the image
var img = new MagickImage("input.JPG");
img.Quality = 100;
img.FilterType = FilterType.Lagrange;
```

[image: Step 0]

```
// Step 1: Increase the canvas size
img.Extent(new MagickGeometry(new Percentage(125), new Percentage(125)), Gravity.Center);
```

[image: Step 1]

```
// Step 2: Apply barrel distortion correction
img.Distort(DistortMethod.Barrel, new[] { -0.92578, 1.3845, -2.09958 });
```

[image: Step 2]

```
// Step 3: Fix the perspective
img.Distort(DistortMethod.Perspective, new double[] { 1072, 1512, 0, 0, 3404, 1524, w, 0, 3100, 2220, w, h, 1484, 2344, 0, h });
```

[image: Step 3]

```
// Step 4: Crop and sharpen
img.Extent(2300, 1000);
img.AdaptiveSharpen();
```

[image: Step 4]

Basically what that does is corrects the eyefish effect produced by the Go Pro Hero 5 camera. So, my question now is how do I do the same in Python:

```python
import PythonMagick

img = PythonMagick.Image(r"input.jpg")

img.quality(100)
img.filterType = PythonMagick.FilterTypes.LagrangeFilter

# Steps here

img.write(r"output.jpg")
```

I cannot find the functions or even similar names inside any ImageMagick wrapper.

Comment: You should check that on the Imagemagick Discourse server at Developers forum. See https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/. I suspect that PythonMagick has not kept up with all the changes to Imagemagick and so does not include the equivalent of distort barrel. See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/

Comment: I am really surprised that the Python options are so rudimentary for ImageMagick, I'll try on those forums. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Wand with Python. See https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/wand/latest/wand.pdf

Comment: I was going to test it but they only support IM6.x, and the repo seemed quite abandoned so I went first with PythonMagick. I think I will use a subprocess, all python wrappers seem a bit abandoned.